# Dictionary Values From Other File

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I am working on trying to gather info from a generator created dictionary. I want to access certain aspects of this dictionary but do not know how to reference the dictionary by name since it is created in another file using a class. It keeps giving me the "no object" error or not iterable.

```
for request in liked_tracks:
  likes_long.append(request)
print(f"the long list: {likes_long}")
print(f"the first entry: {likes_long[0]}") #print just the first track
likes_short = [] # what i want the permalink_url to be stored in
likes_medium = [] #the converted dictionary list.

for x in TrackLike.items():
  print(x)
```

Response:

```
the long list: [TrackLike(created_at=datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 24, 0, 36, 46, tzinfo=tzutc()), kind='like', etc...), TrackLike(info),etc...]

the first entry: TrackLike(created_at=datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 24, 0, 36, 46, tzinfo=tzutc()), kind='like',etc...)

AttributeError: type object 'TrackLike' has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: I don't see any dictionaries there.  I see a list of objects.  You need to look at the object to figure out which properties of the object you want.

Comment: @TimRoberts i know i want a key or identifier with the name of "permalink_url" but am unsure how to iterate through this long list of data to single out what I want

Comment: Have you tried the obvious choice, `for request in liked_tracks:` / `likes.append( request.permalink_url )`?

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue. My response was converted to a container list that had super long strings as each list entry. If I used the split function for every ',' then I could add all of those individual segments to another list and then perform further steps through iteration. @TimRoberts